# MySQL Group Sum amount on the filter by a text

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working on the sum and if, I am able to get the value (amount_description) of a number for Sum, but I am not sure how I can calculation based on the text (varchar and blue highlight).

[image]

As you can see the screenshot as amount, I want the amount based on Amount description on each SKU

So my hope you can advice and how it working

I have tried different many ways but nothing has to work even I write

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN amount_description = 'commission' and amount_description = 'Commission' and amount_description = 'RefundCommission'THEN amount END) AS sku_TOTAL, transaction_type
FROM settlements
Where transaction_type ='refund'
```

I am still rookie in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` function as well as `GROUP BY` to group all the entries with the same SKU together.

```
SELECT
    `transaction_type`,
    `sku`,
    SUM(`amount`) AS `sku_total`
FROM
    `settlements`
WHERE
    `transaction_type` = 'Refund'
    AND `amount_description` IN (
        'Principal', 'Commission', 'RefundCommission'
    )
GROUP BY
    `transaction_type`, -- Doesn't really do anything since there is only one type
    `sku`
```

On the comment about not doing anything: MySQL will often allow this query without that, but most DBMS' require that all fields not in aggregate functions must be in the `GROUP BY` clause. In this case, because there will be only one group (Refund), it doesn't affect the output, and should be included for best practice.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect practice and it working on my side. thank you so much, regarding on the comment, I understand and will take notes on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use group by and sum to get the sum of each amount_description then filter them using having or where to get only some amount_descriptions

please try

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, amount_description
FROM settlements
Where transaction_type ='refund'
GROUP BY amount_description 
having amount_description="commission" or amount_description="Commission" or 
amount_description="RefundCommission"
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, amount_description,sku
FROM settlements
WHERE transaction_type ='refund'
AND ( amount_description="commission" OR amount_description="Commission" OR
        amount_description="RefundCommission" )
GROUP BY amount_description,sku
```

Comment: Have done this but this is not what I have look for, i am more look for a group in each SKU. This query looks good and tidier for another function I might use this.

Comment: Can you explain more ? you want the sum for each sku not for according to amount_description

Comment: Yes, Sum for each SKU and based on by Amount_description, as they are total by (Principal, Commission and RefundCommission)

Comment: ok  you can use
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total,sku
FROM settlements
WHERE transaction_type ='refund'
AND ( amount_description="commission" OR amount_description="Commission" OR
        amount_description="RefundCommission" )
GROUP BY sky